# Are there any built in ways to vertically align text with right aligned button in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Are there any simple non hacky ways to vertically align the text inside a list group item with the text in the button when you 'pull-right' the button?

This goes for a panel header, and pretty much anywhere you want to have a button inline with text, but right aligned...

Example:

'item' text is higher than button text.

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Button 1</button>
      item1
  </li>
  <li href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Button 2</button>
      item2
  </li>
</ul>
```

button isn't right aligned :(

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
      item1
      <button class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
  </li>
  <li href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
      item2
      <button class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

hacky empty button next to text!

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Button 1</button>
      item1
      <button class="btn btn-link">&nbsp;</button>
  </li>
  <li href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Button 2</button>
      item2
      <button class="btn btn-link">&nbsp;</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ofya1n4/

Comment: I think `line-height` and  (or) `transform: translateY()` are your friends here. Admittedly the issue is somewhat unclear to me. Text can be targeted better if it's inside a span or paragraph.

Comment: have you tried text-right bootstrap class?

Comment: Guess my question is really about some built in bootstrap class that would solve this.. there's many ways with line-heights and so on to do it.. I would think that creating a special class (or classes) for a container to take on the correct height and alignment as a btn so that it could use the same less variables for heights and so on.

Comment: @GuyBowden There *is* a bootstrap way to achieve that, but it is designed for inline forms where there is a `<form>` element with `form-horizontal` class, containing a `<label>` element with `control-label` class name. All the thing it does is adding `padding-top: 7px` to the label. See: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/2ofya1n4/5/ (Note that the computed value of `display` of the box should be `block` or `inline-block` to get `padding-top` to work).

Answer (score 0):

Put you text inside span and give span `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` like:

```
span {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 35px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Check [Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/2ofya1n4/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make it with `line-height` line Shikkediel said. I've added `line-height` class to the first two li elements.

Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ofya1n4/4/)